# Slide div blocks on next previous click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how can I slide blocks by clicking controls next - previous.
[image: Screenshot]

My main div is width of 1400px & under some child div has 300px width with floating.

On screen I want to show 3 blocks which is working now on next button click I want this blocks to scroll.

```
<!--blocks-starts-->
    <div class="common-blocks">
        <h2>ADVENTURE</h2>
        <div class="blocks"><!--blocks-starts-->
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
            </div>                
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <div class="blocks"><!--blocks-starts-->
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_06.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Helicopter Tour Of Mumbai</h3>
                <p>Customized The concept of Joy Rides is here. South Mumbai Juhu , Bandra - Worli Sealink, Worli Sea Face, Mahalaxmi Temple and more.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <div class="blocks"><!--blocks-starts-->
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_08.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Scuba Diving</h3>
                <p>Discover a spectacular world, where sound and gravity seem to forget about you for a while.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <div class="blocks"><!--blocks-starts-->
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

    </div><!--common-blocks-ends-->
```

css

```
.common-blocks{
    width:100%;
    width:1400px;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
}

.common-blocks h2{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
}

.blocks{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 40px 20px 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:#454545;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    height:310px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this JS Version :

HTML:-

```
<div class="outer-div">
<h2>ADVENTURE</h2>
<div class="common-blocks" id="common-blocks">

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
            </div>                
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_06.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Helicopter Tour Of Mumbai</h3>
                <p>Customized The concept of Joy Rides is here. South Mumbai Juhu , Bandra - Worli Sealink, Worli Sea Face, Mahalaxmi Temple and more.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_08.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Scuba Diving</h3>
                <p>Discover a spectacular world, where sound and gravity seem to forget about you for a while.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

                            <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
                                <div class="block-img">
                                    <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="block-content">
                                    <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                                    <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--blocks-ends-->

    </div><!--common-blocks-ends-->
    <button class="next">Next</button>
    <button class="prev">Previous</button>
 </div>

<div class="outer-div">
<h2>ADVENTURE</h2>
<div class="common-blocks" id="common-blocks">

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
            </div>

            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
            </div>                
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_06.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Helicopter Tour Of Mumbai</h3>
                <p>Customized The concept of Joy Rides is here. South Mumbai Juhu , Bandra - Worli Sealink, Worli Sea Face, Mahalaxmi Temple and more.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

        <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
            <div class="block-img">
                <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_08.gif" />
            </div>
            <div class="block-content">
                <h3>Scuba Diving</h3>
                <p>Discover a spectacular world, where sound and gravity seem to forget about you for a while.</p>
            </div>
        </div><!--blocks-ends-->

                            <!--blocks-starts--><div class="blocks">
                                <div class="block-img">
                                    <img src="images/foxbox-home-page_version_27_03.gif" />
                                </div>

                                <div class="block-content">
                                    <h3>River Rafting</h3>
                                    <p>Get ready to ride nature's rollercoaster in this once in a lifetime. White Water Rafting experience on the Kundalika River in Kolad.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div><!--blocks-ends-->

    </div><!--common-blocks-ends-->
   <button class="next">Next</button>
   <button class="prev">Previous</button>
 </div>
```

CSS:-

```
.common-blocks{
    width:100%;
    width:1400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:auto;
    transition:all 0.5s;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.common-blocks h2{
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;
}

.blocks{
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px 40px 20px 0;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:#454545;
    padding:0 0 5px 0;
    height:310px
}
.outer-div{
    width:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

jQuery: -

```
var registerEvents = function(){
$(".next").off("click").on("click",function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('disable'))return;
    $(this).addClass('disable');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(event.target).removeClass('disable');
    },510);
    var targetBlock = $(event.target).siblings('.common-blocks');
    var leftMargin = parseInt(targetBlock.css("marginLeft") || 0) ;
    var numberOfBlocks = targetBlock.children(".blocks").length; //    Total Number of blocks 
    var displayCount = 3;//Number of blocks displaying at a time
    if(leftMargin <= (numberOfBlocks-displayCount)*(-300))  // -300 width   of    block in left direction
        return;
    targetBlock.css("marginLeft",parseInt(leftMargin - 300)+"px")
});
$(".prev").off("click").on("click",function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('disable'))return;
    $(this).addClass('disable');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(event.target).removeClass('disable');
    },510);
    var targetBlock = $(event.target).siblings('.common-blocks');
    var leftMargin = parseInt(targetBlock.css("marginLeft") || 0) ;
    if(leftMargin == 0) 
        return;
    targetBlock.css("marginLeft",parseInt(leftMargin + 300)+"px")
});

}();
```

Comment: Thanks. Just little problem. On next click if content gets end then too it still keeps rotating & shows blank spaces. Can you disabled it or if it keeps loop once ends then too it is fine

Comment: Just put a check whether the list end or not. wait, i can edit

Comment: What changes & where you made it. I replaced script but it is working as previous.

Comment: from line number 4 to line number 7 in JS

Comment: so that is working as usual . that problem not solved

Comment: Tell if I have 13 blocks & have to repeat this procedure for all 13 blocks then is it possible without replicate the script & write it saperately for each blocks

Comment: By 13 blocks, what you mean? the block inside common block or the common block itself?   one variable is ther,  'displayCount' , which should be updated with the number of blocks displaying at at time

Comment: I mean 13 common-blocks div

Comment: Then it will be better to use jQUery with lil modification in html structure

Comment: What changes needs to make?

Comment: can you check now? Dont forget to include jQuery. HTML and jQuery part changed

Comment: It won't work if place control buttons inside common-div blocks?

Comment: we are changing the 'margin-left' of 'common-block',. so if the buttons are within the common-block, it also will be moved.

Comment: No. If I place buttons inside common-blocks on top then nothing getting moved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113297/discussion-between-sabith-and-stone).